# Responsive image and objects

Tags: responsive-images

Hello to all I am new to the community, and it comes because I have a big doubt this doubt I've had for a year and I can not get someone to explain me correctly, well getting to the point, I have a website that I created recently but I see that when I place an image or an object when I move the window of my browser everything is deformed, then I discovered a long time ago that to not deform the images or objects I have to make it adapt to any screen, I looked for many tutorials but none worked for me, I work with wordpress, then I want to know how I can do it using the wordpress console, I will attach some pictures.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5dqb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOwnV.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting any question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code writing service!

Answer (score 0):

Use Position Property. Place the image and Blue Background inside a div tag with Relative Parent and set top or bottom and Left or right values.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a novice and I didn't understand anything you said.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).